# "runreadytoruncompiler" error with .net core 3.1 when publishing a single file probject

Tags: .net-core, publishing

I have an F# project that I build this way:

> dotnet publish --nologo -r osx-x64 -c Release --self-contained true /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishTrimmed=true /p:PublishReadyToRun=true

and I get pages of this:

```
RUNREADYTORUNCOMPILER : warning : Could not load type 'System.Resources.IResourceWriter' from assembly 'System.Text.RegularExpressions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. while resolving 0x10000ce - System.Resources.IResourceWriter. [/Users/thomas/Projects/test/test.fsproj]
RUNREADYTORUNCOMPILER : warning : Could not load type 'System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder' from assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. while resolving 0x2000045 - System.Text.Json.JsonWriterOptions. [/Users/thomas/Projects/test/test.fsproj]
RUNREADYTORUNCOMPILER : warning : Could not load type 'System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder' from assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. while resolving 0x2000046 - System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonWriter. [/Users/thomas/Projects/test/test.fsproj]
RUNREADYTORUNCOMPILER : warning : Could not load type 'System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder' from assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. while resolving 0x1000011 - System.Text.Encodings.Web.JavaScriptEncoder. [/Users/thomas/Projects/test/test.fsproj]
RUNREADYTORUNCOMPILER : warning : Could not load type 'System.Text.Encodings.Web.TextEncoder' from assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. while resolving 0x10000ad - System.Text.Encodings.Web.TextEncoder. [/Users/thomas/Projects/test/test.fsproj]
RUNREADYTORUNCOMPILER : warning : Could not load type 'System.Text.Encodings.Web.TextEncoder' from assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. while resolving 0xa00023c - System.Text.Encodings.Web.TextEncoder.FindFirstCharacterToEncodeUtf8. [/Users/thomas/Projects/test/test.fsproj]
RUNREADYTORUNCOMPILER : warning : Could not load type 'System.Text.Encodings.Web.TextEncoder' from assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. while resolving 0xa00023f - System.Text.Encodings.Web.TextEncoder.FindFirstCharacterToEncode. [/Users/thomas/Projects/test/test.fsproj]
```

What does this error mean?

I have another project I build with the exact same command line without any problem.

If I remove the single file attribute, then it will build properly.

How to troubleshoot this? the error message doesn't really explain me what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the project file to fix JavaScriptEncoder:

```
<TrimmerRootAssembly Include="System.Text.Encodings.Web" />
```

And this for IResourceWriter:

```
<TrimmerRootAssembly Include="System.Resources.Writer" />
```

ReadyToRun sometimes needs help (or its just buggy) on what to include, you can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/trimming-options)